# How to convert a Windows CMD Forloop in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, for-loop, while-loop, counter

I have the following code in command shell code.

```
SET MYdir=%NewPath%\%CUST%\SuppliesTypes
SET "MYsCount=1"
SET /p MYsCount="Number of MYs in project? (default: %MYSCount%): "
for /L %%a in (1,1,%MYsCount%) do ( 
    SET /p MYNums="Enter %%a MY Number: " 
    call md "%MYdir%\MY_%%MYNums%%"
    )
SET "MYsCount="
```

However, I am converting my code from CMD to PowerShell.  I do not fully understand the correct way to convert over.  Here might be how it should be done, but it's not working as it just jumps right through.

```
SET MYdir=%NewPath%\%CUST%\Product
SET "MYsCount=1"
SET /p MYsCount="Number of MYs in project? (default: %MYSCount%): "
For ($MYsCount = 1; $MYsCount -eq 10; $MYsCount++){
   SET /p MyNums="Enter %%a Product Numbers: " 
   CALL MD "%MYdir%\%CUST%\Product_%%"
} 
SET "$MYsCount="
```

I've looked at the following sites and articles:

1. [PowerShell Basics: Programming With Loops](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-for-loop,2-845.html) (Helped validate)
2. [How to do a forloop in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219997/how-to-do-a-forloop-in-a-django-template) (Didn't really help)
3. [Windows PowerShell Cookbook, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024132.do)  (Page 170)

I am running this code inside a While-Loop.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You use `$MYsCount -eq 10` as the condition. It should be `$MYsCount -le 10` (less or equal). Just FYI, the rest of the code (everything except loop) in the powershell sample is not powershell code...

Answer (score 3):

You have an interesting amalgam of batch file and powershell there in your second code block. It is hard to read when some things are one language and some things are another. Let's see if we can't get it all into PowerShell here.

```
$MYdir = "$NewPath\$CUST\Product"
$MYsCount = 1
$UserMYsCount = Read-Host "Number of MYs in project? (default: $MYSCount): "
If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($UserMYsCount){
    $UserMYsCount = $MYsCount
}
For ($i = 1; $i -le $UserMYsCount; $I++){
   $MyNums = Read-Host "Enter $i Product Numbers: " 
   New-Item -Path "$MYdir\MY_$MyNums" -ItemType Directory
}
```

Comment: You could do `if ($UserMYsCount -notmatch '^[0-9]+$') {$UserMYsCount = $MYsCount}` to validate rather than `IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: @BenH the `isnullorempty` method is more obvious to the casual reader as to what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is coming from how you are declaring your variables. SET creates the variables as environment variables that powershell does not access natively. Below is how I would write up your section of code:

```
$MYDir = "$env:NewPath\$env:CUST\SuppliesTypes"
$MYsCount = 1
$MYsCount = read-host -prompt "Number of MYs in project? (default: $MYSCount): "
foreach ($a in 0..$MYsCount){
    $MYNums = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter $a Product Numbers: "
    New-Item -Path "$MYDir\MY_$MYNums" -ItemType Directory
}
$MYsCount = $null
```

I used a foreach loop instead of a normal for loop because you were incrementing by one each time and I have noticed a small performance gain from using foreach when the step is not complicated. 0..$variable is a short hand for using each number from 0 to the declared variable.

If you did want to use a for loop as you mentioned then you could use:

```
For ($MYsCount = 1; $MYsCount -eq 10; $MYsCount++){
```

as you had expected. This loop will only stop if the $MYsCount variable equals 10 though so if someone set the variable to something above 10 it would run indefinitely.

Comment: Your `For` loop is a touch off from their intent. You would do something like what I put in my answer for the `For` loop. Good job including the `$env:` stuff though

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure if the goal of the loop was merely to execute the code block a number of times or if there was a particular condition in the rest of the code I wasn't aware of so I thought I'd keep the original bounds checking and include a message about the risk of how the bounds checking was being handled. I like your error handling included in your answer!